# How to do a MySql query in WordPress?

Tags: php, query, mysql

I want to get the last auto-incremented ID's value of a particular table. I found a MySql function on the internet to do that. But I'm not sure how can I use this function in WordPress to get the value.
Here is the query code I found-

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Now, how I can make use of this MySql query in WordPress?

Comment: Is there a particular reason or goal in doing this? E.g. figuring out the post with the highest ID? What have you found so far in your research?

Comment: Yes.
It's a custom database table and I want to get the last inserted value of the auto incremented column.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own MySQL queries by getting [the global `$wpdb` variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and preparing a SQL statement and then getting the results.

```
global $wpdb;
$prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM [your_table] WHERE LAST_INSERT_ID();' );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $prepared_query );
```

Please, be very careful when using this, if you do it incorrectly, it could be very malicious.  With what you're requesting here, you technically don't need to prepare it, but I've gotten in the habit of always preparing my statements just in case they get changed later to be more powerful.

**EDIT**

I think I wrote my query wrong, try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM %s', $table_name );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $prepared_query );
```

If that doesn't work, I found [another resource on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql) dealing with this, since the ID you mentioned was auto-incrementing, and if you are not worried about simultaneous insertions, then you maybe just need `MAX(id)` instead.

```
global $wpdb;
$prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT MAX(id) FROM %s', $table_name );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $prepared_query );
```

Comment: Not working.
Note: I changed the your_table with my table name. Can you check the code again?

Comment: Can you tell me how it broke or at least paste your query so I can see it?

Comment: Here is my code:
`$id = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE LAST_INSERT_ID();" );
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $id );
        echo $id; //output is: Array
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($results, 1).'</pre>'; //Returning all of the row data in a array ` 
But this function/query shuld only returen the last inserted row's auto-incremented value.
From MySql doc: _After inserting a row that generates an AUTO_INCREMENT value, you can get the value like this:_
`mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: Alright, I edited my original answer with 2 new methods.  If neither of them work, I'm not sure what else to do.  Good luck!